# Solving the sin expansion of a function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I am solving this PDE $$2u_{xx}=u_t$$ $$u(x,0)=x$$ $$u(0,t)=u_x(4,t)=0$$.

I found this solution $$u(x,t)=\sum_0^{\infty}\left(D_n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}{4}x\right)\exp\left(\left(\frac{4}{n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)^2t\right)\right)$$

Then, I need to solve the fourier series bellow

$$u(x,0)=\sum_0^{\infty}\left(D_n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}{4}x\right)\right)=x$$

For the period $L=4$. I don't know how to deal with $\frac{\pi}{2}$ inside the sine. How should I solve?

Comment: I think these sines will be orthogonal in the $[0, 4]$ interval. Then you can use the orthogonality condition to find the coefficients $D_n$. And you'll have to calculate the integral $\int_0^4x\sin[(n+1/2)\pi x/4]dx$